# React Hooks - set state to initial state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am using React useState to create an object in state.
This is updated to an object of data after a successful API call.

I have a form that can change this state, but I also have a cancel button.
How can i restore this state to its initial values (after API call) when cancel is clicked?

Should i create another state variable and store initial state there and then update my state based on that?

````
  const [basePosition, setBasePosition] = useState({});
  const [position, setPosition] = useState({
    id: '',
    title: '',
    description: '',
    authoredBy: '',
    createdDate: '',
    lastUpdatedBy: '',
    lastUpdateDate: '',
    sliderResponses: [],
    tileResponses: [{}],
    template: {}
  });```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reset to Initial State with React Hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54895883/reset-to-initial-state-with-react-hooks)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
const initialState = {
    id: '',
    title: '',
};

const Test = () => {
    const [position, setPosition] = useState(initialState);

    return <>
        ...form
        <button onClick={() => setPosition(initialState)}>Reset</button>
    </>;
};
```

Comment: Thanks, out of interest why does initialState have to be outside the component?

Comment: @Paul This is not necessary, but in this case, because data is static it is better to put it outside the component. Otherwise, a new object `initialState` will be created for each render (but repeat again in this case, you will not notice performance problems :) ).

Comment: Hi @Nikita Madeev,  but initialState will update once the GET request is successful and gets the post data. It will then populate that initialState object with that data....

Answer (score 0):

Don't create another state variable just to store initial state as it will cause another re render instead when your component is mounted then intialize your initial state object:

```
let initialState = null;

React.useEffect(() => {
  initialState = position;
},[])
```

When you want to reset to initial state just use:

```
setPosition(initialState);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need not to create another **State**. Just declare an initial state which will not be changed and assign it to the **Position** state when it is needed to be reset. EX:

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'

const YourComponent = () =>{
 const initialState = {
    id: '',
    title: '',
    description: '',
    authoredBy: '',
    createdDate: '',
    lastUpdatedBy: '',
    lastUpdateDate: '',
    sliderResponses: [],
    tileResponses: [{}],
    template: {}
  }
 const [basePosition, setBasePosition] = useState({});
  const [position, setPosition] = useState(initialState);
  const resetState = () =>{
     setPosition(initialState)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question if you should store initial value is Yes.

That would be the easiest way to maintain your code. So put your initial value in a constant:

```js
const INITIAL_VALUES = {
  id: '',
  title: '',
  description: '',
  authoredBy: '',
  createdDate: '',
  lastUpdatedBy: '',
  lastUpdateDate: '',
  sliderResponses: [],
  tileResponses: [{}],
  template: {}
}
```

Than every time you want to use that initial object, just spread it and all is good (spread to lose reference to constant):

```js
const [basePosition, setBasePosition] = useState({});
const [position, setPosition] = useState({...INITIAL_VALUES});
```

And later when you reset:

```js
setPosition({...INITIAL_VALUES})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

// counter 

function Example3() {

    const [initial, setIncrement] = useState(0)


    const increment = () => {
        setIncrement(initial + 1)
    }
    const dincrement = () => {
        setIncrement(initial - 1)
    }


    const reset = () => {

        setIncrement(0)

    }




    return (


        <div>

            <p>{initial}</p>
            <button onClick={increment} >+</button>
            <button onClick={dincrement} >-</button>
            <button onClick={reset}>reset</button>

        </div>


    )




}


export default Example3;
```