# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used

Tags: typescript

I was following TypeScript example provided by Guilherme on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54895883/reset-to-initial-state-with-react-hooks) (pasted bellow).
But I'm getting an error:  *Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string | number | symbol' can't be used to index type 'IState'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'IState'.ts(7053)*
Following [this](https://www.nadershamma.dev/blog/2019/how-to-access-object-properties-dynamically-using-bracket-notation-in-typescript/) article I've tried to add:

```
    const result: IState = { ...state };
    result[action.type as keyof IState] = action.value;
    return result;
```

but this doesn't solve the issue. There are many responses to such question, but I'm missing something.

```
import React, { FC, Reducer, useReducer } from "react";

interface IState {
    email: string;
    password: string;
    passwordConfirmation: string;
    username: string;
}

interface IAction {
    type: string;
    value?: string;
}

const initialState: IState = {
    email: "",
    password: "",
    passwordConfirmation: "",
    username: "",
};

const reducer = (state: IState, action: IAction) => {
    if (action.type === "reset") {
        return initialState;
    }

    const result: IState = { ...state };
    result[action.type] = action.value;
    return result;
};

export const Signup: FC = props => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer<Reducer<IState, IAction>, IState>(reducer, initialState, () => initialState);
    const { username, email, password, passwordConfirmation } = state;

    const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        /* fetch api */

        /* clear state */
        dispatch({ type: "reset" });
    };

    const onChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        dispatch({ type: name, value });
    };

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div>
                <label>
                    Username:
                    <input value={username} name="username" onChange={onChange} />
                </label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>
                    Email:
                    <input value={email} name="email" onChange={onChange} />
                </label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>
                    Password:
                    <input
                        value={password}
                        name="password"
                        type="password"
                        onChange={onChange}
                    />
                </label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>
                    Confirm Password:
                    <input
                        value={passwordConfirmation}
                        name="passwordConfirmation"
                        type="password"
                        onChange={onChange}
                    />
                </label>
            </div>
            <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main cause for that error can be addressed by changing the definition of `IAction` to:

```
interface IAction {
    type: keyof IState;
    value?: string;
}
```

which uses the [`keyof` type operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html) to ensure that the `type` property can only be one of the keys of `IState`.

With this you'll have two other errors though (one of which may have been immediately apparent):

```
main.ts:21:9 - error TS2367: This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'keyof IState' and '"reset"' have no overlap.

21     if (action.type === "reset") {
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

main.ts:26:5 - error TS2322: Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.

26     result[action.type] = action.value;
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Found 2 errors.
```

So, looking at the first error, it's clear that, in order for the `type` property of `IAction` to be acceptable, it must also include `reset`, which can be done by changing the definition of `IAction` to:

```
interface IAction {
    type: keyof IState | "reset";
    value?: string;
}
```

However, this doesn't resolve the second error, which is related to the fact that the `value` property is typed as `string | undefined` (due to the use of `?`), but the various properties on `IState` are all typed as `string` (not allowing the possibility of being assigned `undefined`).

There are, as I see it, three options:

- make `IAction.value` a non-optional `string`
- make all the properties of `IState` optional `string`s
- change `IAction` to a discriminated [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) (as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56949513/typescript-type-of-a-property-dependent-on-another-property-within-the-same-obj#answer-56950384))

The first two are both pretty straight-forward, but have far-reaching implications as to what uses of the are allowed or required to do, so let's look at the third. Changing the definition of `IAction` to:

```
type IAction = {
    type: keyof IState;
    value: string;
} | {
    type: "reset";
};
```

we have defined a type that is the union of two types, and instances of this type can be discriminated through use of [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#equality-narrowing). Thus, in the reducer:

```
const reducer = (state: IState, action: IAction) => {

    // `action` can be either:
    //   { type: keyof IState; value: string; }
    // or:
    //   { type: "reset"; }

    if (action.type === "reset") {

        // `action` can only be:
        //   { type: "reset" }
        // as the `type` property equals "reset"

        return initialState;
    }

    // `action` can only be:
    //   { type: keyof IState; value: string; }
    // as the `type` property _doesn't_ equal "reset"

    const result: IState = { ...state };
    result[action.type] = action.value;
    return result;
};
```

In this way, you've preserved the type safety of the type, without having to reduce the type safety of other types (eg making `IState` properties optional) or having needless values for some fields (eg making `IAction.value` non-optional and forcing the `"reset"` case to also have a `value`).

##### Handling Arbitrary Values

From your code, there is one place where an `IAction` is created with arbitrary values:

```
const onChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    dispatch({ type: name, value });
};
```

which, as you've noted in your comment, will produce an error similar to:

```
main.ts:44:15 - error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"reset" | keyof IState'.

44     dispatch({type: name, value });
                 ~~~~

  main.ts:11:5
    11     type: keyof IState;
           ~~~~
    The expected type comes from property 'type' which is declared here on type 'IAction'


Found 1 error.
```

This is due to `HTMLInputElement.name` being typed `string`, which can be assigned values beyond the restricted set allowed (`keyof IState`). One option, as you've discovered, is to change the invocation of `dispatch` to:

```
dispatch({type: name as keyof IState, value });
```

using a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to inform the type checker that `name` is of a compatible type. You can be a bit more rigorous and make use of a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates), which is a way of defining some runtime logic that, if met, would indicate that the type is compatible:

```
const isAction = (action: { type: string, value?: string }): action is IAction => {
    return action.type in ["email", "password", "passwordConfirmation", "username"];
}
```

used in `onChange` with something like:

```
const onChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const action = { type: name, value };

    if (isAction(action)) {
        dispatch(action);
    }
};
```

One downside of this is the need to manually list all the keys of `IState`; if there is a change to the interface in future (addition or removal of a property) then the runtime type predicate would also need to be updated, otherwise it would no longer be valid.

Comment: Thank you for explaining step by step. It became clearer how it works. Unfortunately, I'm getting an error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'keyof IState | "reset"'.ts(2322)
test.ts(15, 5): The expected type comes from property 'type' which is declared here on type 'IAction'. But everything of IState is declared as strings. Why is it complaining?

Comment: Managed to solve by adding keyof IState in dispatch: dispatch({ type: name as keyof IState, value });. Thanks!

Comment: @Weilire sounds like you've got it in hand, but I'll add a section about restricting that a bit more at the call-site of `dispatch`.